# Discrepancy between the results of inbuild sum and pd.Series.sum function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sum

This is the Series which I am using,

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Wd3czXj9Fc/

```
>>> sum(series)
185048.7799999991
>>> series.sum()
185048.78000000003
```

Why is there a difference between those values? Although there's a floating point error associated with both the values but that shouldn't be the reason for this difference.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is there a difference between those values? Although there's a floating point error associated with both the values but that shouldn't be the reason for this difference.

As alluded to in your question, it's due to floating point in precision. Your decimal numbers are being approximated so there is a slight different when using Python build-in `sum()` vs using `pandas.Series.sum()` (which actually calls `numpy.sum()`.

The `sum()` built-in isn't intended to be used for accurate floating point arithmetic. " To add floating point values with extended precision, see `math.fsum()`." [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)